# Using TypeTags to Check if Expected Type Matches Actual

Tags: scala

Given:

```
sealed trait Parent
case class Boy(info: String) extends Parent
case class Girl(info: String) extends Parent
```

Then, I wrote the following `f` function. Given a `result` and expected result type, it prints out whether the check succeeded or not:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def f[A:TypeTag, B:TypeTag](result: A): Unit = typeOf[A] match { 
     | case t if t =:= typeOf[B] => println("good")
     | case _                    => println("bad")
     | }
f: [A, B](result: A)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A], implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[B])Unit
```

Then, I ran it:

```
scala> f[Boy, Girl](Boy("foo"))
bad

scala> f[Boy, Boy](Boy("foo"))
good
```

For my test purposes (ignoring the usage of a `println` statement to indicate success), is my usage of `TypeTag`'s correct? Also, is there any risk of runtime exceptions in `f`? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is my usage of TypeTag's correct?

`TypeTag` isn't really needed if you are manually supplying type parameters. This is roughly equivalent to:

```
def f[A](result: A): Unit = ???
```

`f[Girl](boy)` won't even compile if `boy` is a `Boy`, so the failure case wouldn't be useful.

For `def f[A: TypeTag, B: TypeTag](result: A): Unit`, the actual instance of `result` isn't needed, because you're manually comparing `TypeTag`s of `A` and `B`, you manually specify the type parameters. It is equivalent to saying `typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[B]` without an instance.

> Also, is there any risk of runtime exceptions in `f`?

Not really. You'd have to be doing something really nefarious, like making your own `TypeTag`s:

```
scala> implicit val tt: TypeTag[Boy] = null.asInstanceOf[TypeTag[Boy]]
tt: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Boy] = null

scala> f[Boy, Girl](Boy("foo"))
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So long as you use the compiler-generated `TypeTag`, it should be fine.

Comment: `the actual instance of result isn't needed, because you're manually comparing` In that case then, I'd simply call the `type` method? Example: `case class F(x: Int) | val y = F(5) |  typeOf[y.type]`?

Comment: If you want the type of an instance, you would need a `TypeTag`, but the problem is you need two type parameters: one that you want to infer, and one that you one to provide, but Scala provides no way to provide one and infer the other.

Comment: @m-z Actually, there is a way to achieve this result. (Also, I'd clarify that your first sentence applies to this specific case, not in general.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can provide one parameter and infer the other:

```
case class F[B: TypeTag] {
  def apply[A: TypeTag](x: A) = println(typeOf[A] =:= typeOf[B])
}

F[Girl].apply(Boy("Foo")) // Boy inferred for A
```